# New Relic plugin on Heroku: push fails with `uninitialized constant NewRelic::Logger::INFO`

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, newrelic

Had new relic up and working fine, but now the push fails during asset precompile. It has to do with the 'newrelic_plugin' gem, because the push worked fine after removing that line from my gemfile and re-bundling.

I have the heroku lab 'user-env-compile' enabled, not sure if it's relevant.

Here's the full stack trace; any help would be much appreciated:

```
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
       ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
       ** Execute assets:environment
       ** Invoke environment (first_time)
       ** Execute environment
       rake aborted!
       uninitialized constant NewRelic::Logger::INFO
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:131:in `log_level_for'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:119:in `set_log_level!'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/agent/agent_logger.rb:13:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:62:in `new'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:62:in `init_plugin'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:40:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:257:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:233:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-0b3a078a2481/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_k8jk6mc5x6ch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

Comment: Hi Jay,
I work for New Relic and we'd love to help. We'd be able to troubleshoot your situation better if you wrote in to support@newrelic.com. When you write to us, could you please expand upon why you are including the `newrelic_plugin` gem? Why are you using it in conjunction with `newrelic_rpm` (you should only need newrelic_rpm)? Including the URL to this StackOverflow question would also be helpful. Thanks!